# Как решить проблему c закрывающим тегом в IntelliSense в Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: html, visual-studio, вёрстка, intellisense

Переходя на верстку в Visual Studio 2015 с использованием IntelliSense столкнулся с проблемой. Суть проблемы:

Есть тег. Любой, например `<p></p>`. Мне нужно добавить класс. Я ставлю курсор так `<p|></p>` жму ctrl+v, получаю `<ppasted></ppasted>`, ставлю курсор так `<p|pasted></ppasted>`, жму пробел, и получаю вместо `<p pasted></p>` такой закрывающий тег `<p pasted></ppasted>`.

Я понимаю как это работает, но мне постоянно неудобно редактировать код таким образом, всегда приходится проверять, не изменился ли в итоге закрывающий тег. На проверку тратится лишнее время, а если не проверять, то можно допускать такие ошибки в коде.

Как мне решить эту проблему, как решаете её вы во время верстки?

Comment: Например, используем Atom . . .

Comment: Я отключаю Automatic Brace Completion, т. к. эта фича больше создаёт проблем, чем помогает. Смотрите Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML. Также я отключаю её в C#, а можно вообще во всех языках сразу.

Comment: Проверил - в данном случае это всё равно не помогает.